# prove the relation for the matrix element

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a_0, a_1, ... a_n $ be non-zero numbers such that
$$ det \begin{pmatrix} a_0&a_1&a_2...&a_k\\ 
                       a_1&a_2&a_3...&a_{k+1}\\
                       a_2&a_3&a_4...&a_{k+2}\\
                        . & .  &.    & .\\
                         . & .  &.    & .\\
                        a_k&a_{k+1}&a_{k+2}...&a_{2k}\\
\end{pmatrix}=0$$
prove that $a_k = a_0\cdot q^k,  k= 1,....,n, q \neq 0$

I thought it was circulant matrix.

I also tried to find a pattern by looking at the lower order determinants, but it didn't work

I have no idea now how to do it.

Comment: Not sure what the determinant is, but it's called a Hankel matrix.

Comment: The determinant is zero iff the matrix has nontrivial nullspace (or, iff its columns are linearly dependent). Basically, we have to prove that the nullspace is actually of dimension $k$. This might get you started..

Comment: Are you sure the statement is correctly stated? What is $n$? It doesn't appear in your matrix. As an answer below shows, the statement as it stands is false.

Answer (score 4):

If my understanding of the problem is correct, the statement is actually wrong. So you won't be able to prove it.

Here is an counter example

$$
\left|\begin{aligned}
   1 && 1 && 2 \\
   1 && 2 && 2 \\
   2 && 2 && 4
\end{aligned}\right| = 0
$$

but here $\{a_i\}$ is $\{1,1,2,2,4\}$, which does not follow the pattern $a_k = a_0 \cdot q^k$

Comment: actually $a_k = a_0\cdot q^k$ means the rank(A) = 1. But rank(A) < k is enough to get det(A) = 0.